# String Array implementation is returning segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

```
int main(void)
{
    const char* line = "This isn't working";
    char* str[10];
    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        int j = 0;
        str[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
        while(line[index] != ' ')
        {

            str[i][j] = line[index];
            j++;
            index++;
        }
        index++;
        if(index == strlen(line) - 1)
            break;


    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }



}
```

I am trying to create a string array where I want to store words from my variable "line". But the code I've written is giving "segmentation fault" please help

Comment: You are not null-terminating your strings.

Comment: ...nor are you loop limiting to ensure your appendage of characters doesn't overrun the unchecked allocated space you hopefully acquired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the sample string `"This isn't working"` your `while(line[index] != ' ')` will work forever. Length check is done only once, after this loop. Because of it you've got undefined behavior. It can be a main reason of your problem. Good article on this topic ["Undefined behavior can result in time travel"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

To fix it change `while` loop condition to:

```
int strLength = strlen(line);
while (index < strLength && line[index] != ' ')
{
  // Do the job here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C strings need to be terminated with NUL. After your inner loop, you can say `str[i][j] = '\0'` to fix this problem.

There is at least one other problem with the code: When you get to the last word of `line`, there won't be a space to terminate the inner loop, so the inner loop will keep running and running, reading unrelated memory, until you happen to get to a space character in Never Never Land.